# I am not able to import csv even after installing it

Tags: python, csv

[image: csv not importing]

Hello, I am new to python. I have already pip installed csv even then I am getting this error please guide me through this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, please [edit] your question to include your code and error message as [formatted text](/editing-help#code).

Comment: You don't need to install the `csv` module via pip; it's included in all Python versions starting from 2.3. What happens when you run `pip uninstall csv`, then try running your code again?

Comment: You're not importing the library module but your own file called "csv.py", which is located in your home directory, and it is is not a Python source file but a Jupyter notebook file. Rename that file.